# Add spaces between 9-digit binded number using StringFormat, xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a binded number that I want to add spaces in-between. Eg. Currently it displays 123456789 , I want it to display 123 456 789. Anyone knows how to do this using stringFormat?

**My xaml**

```
<Label Text="{Binding CardNumber}" TextColor="#1481BA" />
```

Comment: Not entirely sure but try `Text="{Binding CardNumber,  StringFormat={0:### ### ###}"`

Comment: You're right @Nkosi. Post it as answer to community =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CardNumber is a string so the format Nkosi suggested didn't work. This is my solution:

```
                    foreach(var i in Items)
                    {
                        string cardNum = i.CardNumber;
                        int cardInt = 3;

                        while(cardInt < cardNum.Length)
                        {
                            cardNum = cardNum.Insert(cardInt, " ");
                            cardInt += 4;
                        }
                        i.CardNumber = cardNum;

                    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following format `StringFormat={0:### ### ###}`

For example

```
<Label Text="{Binding CardNumber, StringFormat={0:### ### ###}" TextColor="#1481BA" />
```

Comment: This did not work in my xamarin.forms xaml, I instead formatted my number in the .cs class

Comment: You could also consider using a value converter.

Comment: @JanineAlexander, This format should work to number types. Is the `CardNumber` property's type `string`?